# Simplify and generalize implementation of check conditions

Tags: java, class, oop, interface, rule-engine

How could I implement/generalize the code below (just illustrative) to shorten/simplify the implementation of different check conditions? For example: by replacing new Model1().checkCondition(teste) by something like "teste -> isBlue || isSad. Thus:

1. avoid having to implement classes to implement different check conditions
2. avoid having to pass the Str multiple times to each method is... (e.g. isSad(string) || isBlue(string))

Thank you,
António.

```
public class Main {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        String teste = "bigbluesad";
        
        System.out.println(new Model1().checkCondition(teste));
        
        System.out.println(new Model2().checkCondition(teste));
        
        System.out.println(new Model3().checkCondition(teste));
        
    }

}

class Model1 implements Interface {
    
    public boolean checkCondition(String str) {
        return isBlue(str) || isSad(str);
    }
    
}

class Model2 implements Interface {
    
    public boolean checkCondition(String str) {
        return isBlue(str) && isHappy(str);
    }
    
}

class Model3 implements Interface {
    
    public boolean checkCondition(String str) {
        return isGreen(str) && isSad(str);
    }
    
}

interface Interface {
    boolean checkCondition(String str);
    
    default boolean isGreen(String str) {
        return str.contains("green");
    }
    
    default boolean isSmall(String str) {
        return str.contains("small");
    }
    
    default boolean isBlue(String str) {
        return str.contains("blue");
    }
    
    default boolean isHappy(String str) {
        return str.contains("happy");
    }
    
    default boolean isSad(String str) {
        return str.contains("sad");
    }
}
```

Comment: I am looking at transforming the main method code to something like: System.out.println(teste -> isBlue || isSad)

Comment: Post clarifications as edits to the Question rather than as Comments.

Comment: A more realistic practical scenario might improve this Question.

Answer (score 0):

Predicates was what I was looking:

```
package testRulesEngine;

import java.util.function.Predicate;

public class Main {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        String teste = "bigbluesad";
        
        Predicate<String> isBlue = x -> x.contains("blue");
        
        Predicate<String> isGreen = x -> x.contains("green");
        
        Predicate<String> isSad = x -> x.contains("sad");       
        
        System.out.println(isBlue.and(isGreen).and(isSad).test(teste));
        
    }

}
´´´
```